# Spy not called on action

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, redux

I'm trying to render a component into Mocha and don't really know why I get this error: [image]

Anyone knows why this happens? I'm passing props manually, since Enzyme doesn't really cover connect() good enough when wrapping your own container with itself.

```
import chai from 'chai'
import React from 'react'
import { shallow, props } from 'enzyme'
import sinon from 'sinon'
import PureTestNest from '../../components/CounterNest'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import sinonChai from 'sinon-chai'


const expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(sinonChai);


function setup(value = 0) {
  const component = shallow(
    <PureTestNest value={value} doIncreaseNumber={doIncreaseNumber} store={store} />
  )
  let doIncreaseNumber =  sinon.spy()

  return {
    component: component,
    doIncreaseNumber,
    buttons: component.find('button')
  }
}

const middlewares = [thunk]
let mockStore = configureStore(middlewares)
let component;
const getState = {}
const store = mockStore(getState)

describe('Components --CounterNest', () => {

  it('should increment an value on a click', () => {
    const { buttons, doIncreaseNumber } = setup()
    buttons.at(0).simulate('click')
    expect(doIncreaseNumber).to.have.been.called()
  });

});
```

Comment: When testing connected components, [the redux docs recommend](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html#connected-components) not testing the connected component, but rather the component that you're connecting (before it's connected). This requires that you export the component as well (as a named export), but that's fine for this case I think.

Comment: yes, I'm exporting the component first before connect, so it should work based on this.

Answer (score 1):

Create the spy before using it in your component?

```
function setup(value = 0) {
  let doIncreaseNumber =  sinon.spy()

  const component = shallow(
    <PureTestNest value={value} doIncreaseNumber={doIncreaseNumber} store={store} />
  )

  return {
    component: component,
    doIncreaseNumber,
    buttons: component.find('button')
  }
}
```

Im not familiar with Mocha (Jasmine user)